# special condition of 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: python, opencv, mse

i am trying to calculate the MSE in order to gain the output of PSNR

```
def mse(imageA, imageB):
  err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2)
  err /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])
  return err

if __name__ == '__main__':

  for i in range(1,7):
      result=cv2.imread('./ct-result/tr' + str(i) + '.bmp')
      recover = cv2.imread('./rs' + str(i) + '.bmp')
      mse=mse(result,recover)
      psnr=10*math.log10((255**2)/mse)
      print(psnr)
```

I encounter a weird situation while i use for loop to calculate 1~6 pictures
it appears 'numpy.float64' object is not callable on 2~6 pictures 
[image]

However when I change str(i) into number such as 2,3... it works
i have no idea what is going on
please help me

you can see form the pictures above that console show the first output of the loop while the following are encounter 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

However i simply change str(i) into 2,3 and so on it works??
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a function named `mse()`, but later on you call this line of code:

```
mse=mse(result,recover)
```

In doing so, you have redefined `mse` to be something else, and it isn't a function anymore.

Use a different name for storing the result of calling `mse()`.

```
mse_output = mse(result,recover)
psnr=10*math.log10((255**2)/mse_output)
```